# Why doesn't Django allow me to use /static/ as URL for static files?

Tags: django

I have the following in my urls.py

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        (r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True}),
    )
```

And it does not work. I always get `'filename.txt' could not be found`
If I change the URL from `r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$'` to anything else, like for example `r'^staticabc/(?P<path>.*)$'` it works.

Any idea how can I get this URL working?

Comment: What's your `STATIC_URL`?

Comment: STATIC_URL = '/static/'

Comment: STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "public", "static")

Comment: although I've never used above method to serve static (I've been using `urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()`), that problem is weird

Comment: What version of django are you using?

Comment: Latest version - 1.5.1

Comment: If so, why don't you use `{% static 'path/to/file' %}` template tag? it will pickup the `STATIC_URL` in `settings.py` for URL

Answer (score 1):

see: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#configuring-static-files

In the "Serving the files" info box, it explains that this is done for you automatically if `DEBUG = True`.

The version that it uses serves static files from the locations discovered by your [`STATICFILES_FINDERS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-STATICFILES_FINDERS)

The extra definition you're providing overrides this one, and ONLY serves files from the `STATIC_ROOT`, which will be empty unless you've just run `collectstatic` will be empty.